# Fuel Pressure Relief Procedures - Evaluating Different Approaches

Tags: fuel-system, testing

Relieving fuel system pressure is obviously an important prerequisite to many repairs and maintenance tasks. However, it seems as if there are a variety of recommendations to relieve the fuel pressure. Perhaps the two most common methods, at least for fuel injected systems, are pulling the fuel pump relay and bleeding at the Schrader or similar valve.

Ordinarily, I might assume that the appropriate approaches varies with the vehicle. While this still might be true, for the same vehicle (a 1996 Chevy G10/Express van), my Chilton's and Haynes manual each recommended a different method (the relay approach vs bleeding as the valve).

Personally, when I changed the fuel filter on the van, I pulled the relay, started it, and let it die (as recommended by the manual I had at the time).  When I pulled the filter, it seemed as if quite a bit more fuel sprayed than I was accustomed to (this was not my first time changing a fuel filter, but my previous vehicle was a TBI). I am wondering if using a bleeder valve would have perhaps done a better job.

As such, I have the a couple questions:

- Is there any universal (or nearly universal) method for safely and effectively relieving the fuel pressure on any given fuel-injected vehicle, or will this vary extensively? If not, what determines the appropriate method; for example, is it the form of fuel injection used (CSFI, MPFI, etc)?
- In general, is either pulling the relay or bleeding the line more effective?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that relieving the pressure does not eliminate normal atmospheric pressure. Depending on the location of your fuel filter, residual fuel still in the line may have seemed to spray out just due to the height of the fuel still in the lines. The bleed valve on my truck (at the fuel rail) is about 2' higher than my fuel filter (on the frame rail bottom driver's side), 1' of height = approx. .5 psi. = 1 psi pressure at the filter *even when de-pressured*.

Answer (score 1):

I would always find a safe way to relieve the pressure : undoing a connector with suitable personal protection and perhaps a rag over the connector.

IMHO just removing the relay may not reduce the pressure rapidly - waiting a suitable amount of time may also be necessary.

The method used must match the system - some run at higher pressures and have accumulators to reduce the pump on time.